# Не получается сохранить информацию в файл sum.txt в с++

Tags: c++, файлы, vector

в коде работают все файлы кроме:"sum.txt" и "profit.txt".Проблема в том,что в них хранится информация из вектора,но при закрытии программы файл обнуляется.Ниже сам код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



class Human
{
protected:
    string initials;
    string gender;
    int age;
};


class Worker :Human
{
protected:
    string specialization;
    float salary;
    int shift_number;
    string post;
};



class Accountant :Worker
{
protected:
    ofstream fout;
    fstream fout_1;
    ofstream profit;
    fstream profit_1;
protected:
    vector<int>Sum_cost;
    vector<int>Sum_profit;
    ofstream Sum_Cost;
    ifstream Sum_Cost_1;
    ofstream Sum_Profit;
    ifstream Sum_Profit_1;

public:

    Accountant() {
        fout.open("costCalculation.txt", ios::app);
        if (!fout.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        fout_1.open("costCalculation.txt");
        if (!fout_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        profit.open("profitCalculation.txt",ios::app);
        if (!profit.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        profit_1.open("profitCalculation.txt");
        if (!profit_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Cost.open("sum.txt");
        if (!Sum_Cost.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Profit.open("profit.txt");
        if (!Sum_Profit.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Profit_1.open("profit.txt", ios::app);
        if (!Sum_Profit_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Cost_1.open("sum.txt", ios::app);
        if (!Sum_Cost_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        
        
           
        
    }

    ~Accountant() {
        if (fout.is_open()) {
            fout.close();
        }
        if (fout_1.is_open()) {
            fout_1.close();
        }
        if (profit.is_open()) {
            profit.close();
        }
        if (profit_1.is_open()) {
            profit_1.close();
        }
        if (Sum_Cost.is_open()) {
            Sum_Cost.close();
        }
        
        if (Sum_Profit.is_open()) {
            Sum_Profit.close();
        }
        if (Sum_Profit_1.is_open()) {
            Sum_Profit_1.close();
        }
        if (Sum_Cost_1.is_open()) {
            Sum_Cost_1.close();
        }
        
    }
    void switch_accountant()
    {
        
        while (true) {
            
            int choice;
            cout << "Выберите варианте" << endl;
            cout << "1. Работа с затратами" << endl;
            cout << "2. Работа с прибылью" << endl;
            cout << "0. Выход " << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 0) {
                break;
            }

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                 cost_calculation();
                break;
            case 2:
                profit_calculation();
                break;
            
            }
        }
 
    }
    void cost_calculation(){//-Подсчет затрат()
            int choice;
            int value;
            int sum_cost = 0;
            int cost;
            while (true) {
                cout << "Выберите варианте" << endl;
                cout << "1. Есть новые затраты" << endl;
                cout << "2. Нет новых затрат" << endl;
                cout << "0. Выход " << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                        cout << "Введите новые затраты" << endl;
                        cin >> cost;
                        fout << " " << cost;
                        while (!fout_1.eof()) {
                            fout_1 >> value;
                            sum_cost += value;


                        }
                        sum_cost = sum_cost + cost;
                    cout <<"Всего потратили:" << sum_cost << endl;
                    Sum_cost.push_back(sum_cost);
                    for (int value_sum : Sum_cost) {
                        Sum_Cost << value_sum << endl;
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    while (!fout_1.eof()) {
                        fout_1 >> value;
                        sum_cost += value;
                    }
                    cout <<"Всего потратили:" << sum_cost << endl;
                    Sum_cost.push_back(sum_cost);
                    for (int value_sum : Sum_cost) {
                        Sum_Cost << value_sum << endl;
                    }
                    break;
           
                    }

                
                
            }
            
           
    }
    
    void profit_calculation() {//-Подсчет прибыли()
        int value_1;
        int cost_profit;
        int sum_profit = 0;
        cout << "Введите прибыль" << endl;
        cin >> cost_profit;
        profit << " " << cost_profit;
        while (!profit_1.eof()) {
            profit_1 >> value_1;
            sum_profit += value_1;
        }
        sum_profit = sum_profit + cost_profit;
        cout << "Всего заработали:" << sum_profit<< endl;
        Sum_profit.push_back(sum_profit);
        for (int value_sum : Sum_profit) {
            Sum_Profit << value_sum << endl;
        }
    }
   
  
};



class Mechanic : public Worker {
private:
    ofstream report;
    fstream report_1;
    string rep;

public:
    Mechanic() {
        report.open("mechanicReport.txt", ios::app);
        if (!report.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        report_1.open("mechanicReport.txt");
        if (!report_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
    }

    ~Mechanic() {
        if (report.is_open()) {
            report.close();
        }
        if (report_1.is_open()) {
            report_1.close();
        }

        
    }

    void Make_report_work() {
        string carBrand;
        string repairType;
        int repairTime;

        while (true) {
            int choice;
            cout << "1. Выберите машину" << endl;
            cout << "2. Выберите тип ремонта" << endl;
            cout << "3. Укажите затраченное время" << endl;
            cout << "0. Выход" << endl;
            cin >> choice;

            if (choice == 0) {
                break;
            }

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                BrandSelection();
                break;
            case 2:
                RepairTypeSelection();
                break;
            case 3:
                RepairTime();
                break;
            }

        }




    }

    void BrandSelection() {
        while (true) {
            int choice;
            cout << "Выберите марку машины:" << endl;
            cout << "1. Lada" << endl;
            cout << "2. BMW" << endl;
            cout << "3. Toyota" << endl;
            cout << "4. Volkswagen" << endl;
            cout << "5. Hyundai" << endl;
            cout << "0. Выход" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 0) {
                break;
            }

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                rep = "Я чинил машину марки:Lada";
                break;
            case 2:
                rep = "Я чинил машину марки:BMW";
                break;
            case 3: 
                rep =  "Я чинил машину марки:Toyota";
                break;
            case 4: 
                rep = "Я чинил машину марки:Volkswagen";
                break;
            case 5:
                rep =  "Я чинил машину марки:Hyundai";
                break;
            }
            
        }
        report << rep;
    }


    void RepairTypeSelection() {

        // Реализуйте выбор типа ремонта аналогичным образом
        while (true) {
            int choice;
            cout << "Выберите тип ремонта:" << endl;
            cout << "1. Замена масла" << endl;
            cout << "2. Ремонт двигателя" << endl;
            cout << "3. Замена калес" << endl;
            cout << "4. Профилактический осмотр" << endl;
            cout << "0. Выход" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 0) {
                break;
            }

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                rep =  " Я произвел замену масла за";
                break;
            
            case 2:
                rep = " Я произвел ремонт двигателя за";
                break;
            
            case 3:
                rep =  " Я произвел замену колес за";
                break;
            
            case 4:
                rep =  " Я совершил проф.осмотр за";
                break;
            }
        }
        report << rep;
    }
    void RepairTime() {
        int repairTime;
        cout << "Введите время затрат (в часах): ";
        cin >> repairTime;
        report <<" "<< repairTime;
    }
    void Reprot() {
        int value;
        while (!report_1.eof()) {
            report_1 >> value;
        }
    }
};

class Manager:Accountant,Mechanic
{
private:
    ifstream Sum_Profit_1;
    ifstream Sum_Cost_1;
    ofstream Sum_Cost;
    ofstream Sum_Profit;
public:
    Manager() {
        Sum_Cost.open("sum.txt", ios::app);
        if (!Sum_Cost.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Profit.open("profit.txt", ios::app);
        if (!Sum_Profit.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Profit_1.open("profit.txt");
        if (!Sum_Profit_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        Sum_Cost_1.open("sum.txt");
        if (!Sum_Cost_1.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
    }
    ~Manager() {
        if (Sum_Cost.is_open()) {
            Sum_Cost.close();
        }

        if (Sum_Profit.is_open()) {
            Sum_Profit.close();
        }
        if (Sum_Profit_1.is_open()) {
            Sum_Profit_1.close();
        }
        if (Sum_Cost_1.is_open()) {
            Sum_Cost_1.close();
        }
    }
    void switch_Manager()
    {

        while (true) {

            int choice;
            cout << "Выберите варианте" << endl;
            cout << "1. Отчет Бугхалтерии" << endl;
            cout << "2. Отчет Механиков" << endl;
            cout << "0. Выход " << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 0) {
                break;
            }

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                Result();
                break;
            case 2:
                
                break;
            
            }
        }

    }
    
    void Result() {
        string LastLine;
        string lastline;
        string CurrentLine;
        string Currentline;
        while (getline(Sum_Cost_1, CurrentLine)) {
            LastLine = CurrentLine;
        }
        cout << "Всего затрат:" << LastLine << endl;;
        while (getline(Sum_Profit_1, Currentline)) {
            lastline = Currentline;
        }
        cout << "Всего Заработали:" << lastline << endl;
    }

  void information_client(){

  }//-побаловаться с вектором и map
};




class Client :Human
{
protected:
    int discount_card_number;
    int phone_number;
private:
    //float pay_order(){} Оплатить заказ()

};

class Automobile
{
private:
    string brand;
    string car_number;
    int mass;
    string body_type;
    string year_release;
};





int main()
{
    Mechanic mechanic;
    Accountant accountant;
    Manager manager;
    int choice; // переменнай для выбора
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");



    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Выберите действие:" << endl;
        cout << "1. Взаимодействовать с бугхалтерией" << endl;
        cout << "2. Прочитать отчет менеджера" << endl;
        cout << "3. Составить отчет механика " << endl;
        cout << "4. Увидеть информацию о клиентах" << endl;
        cout << "0. Выход " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            
            accountant.switch_accountant();
            break;
        case 2:
            manager.switch_Manager();
            break;
        case 3:
            mechanic.Make_report_work();
            break;

        }



    }
}
P.S. Заранее спасибо за помощь
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вы открываете файлы дважды в одном классе? 2. Зачем вы их опять объявляете в классе-наследнике (Manager), если они уже объявлены в родителе Accountant? А вообще-то ковыряться в более чем 500 строках без пояснения, что делает программа, что нужно вводить, чтоб воспроизвести ошибку etc etc — вряд ли найдутся энтузиасты... Вот если бы был [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: добрый день,2 раза я открыл файл скорее от отчаянья,пока пытался решить проблему .А весь код я скинул так-как не совсем уверен в месте где может быть ошибка,ведь в других файлах все работало.По поводу отсутствия комментариев согласен,моя ошибка.